# Dataset keeps on using linear regression instead of decision tree model

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I wanted to use Decision Tree Model on my dataset, but no matter what I do, it keeps on using Linear Regression. The data is different, but the chart is still the same.

Basically, I made a code for the linear regression.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
linreg.fit(x_train,y_train)
y_pred = linreg.predict(x_test)
print(y_pred)

#Regression Chart
lidata = pd.DataFrame({'Actual':y_test,'Predict':y_pred})
sns.jointplot(x='Actual',y='Predict',data=lidata,kind='reg')

#Plotting predicted and test value
lidata = pd.DataFrame({'Actual':y_test,'Predict':y_pred})
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
lidata = lidata.reset_index()
lidata = lidata.drop(['index'],axis=1)
plt.plot(lidata[:50])
plt.legend(['Actual','Predict'])
```

Here is the result:

```
[259015.28102071 477691.37470101 183694.44706634 ... 320526.31718784
 173087.6503445  221971.14827993]
```

[image]

Then I tried using the Decision Tree Model.

```
DT.fit(x_train,y_train)
y_dtpred = DT.predict(x_test)
print(y_dtpred)

lidata = pd.DataFrame({'Actual':y_test,'Predict':y_dtpred})
sns.jointplot(x='Actual',y='Predict',data=lidata,kind='reg')

lidata = pd.DataFrame({'Actual':y_test,'Predict':y_dtpred})
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
lidata = lidata.reset_index()
lidata = lidata.drop(['index'],axis=1)
plt.plot(lidata[:50])
plt.legend(['Actual','Predict'])
```

Here is the result:

```
[414300. 461400. 172100. ... 458500. 218400. 291800.]
```

[image]

I don't know how to make the chart use decision tree model instead of linear regression. I tried to change the values, but it's still the same. Can anyone help me?

By the way, this is the rest of the code:

```
from pandas import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from math import *

import numpy as num
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
%matplotlib inline

import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="white", color_codes=True)

data = DataFrame(read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Datasets/housing.csv"))

print(len(data.columns))
row_count = len(data)
print(row_count)

data.head()

#Looking for missing data
na = pd.concat([data.isnull().sum()],axis=1)
na[na.sum(axis=1)>0]

#Filling the dataset with the mean values
data['total_bedrooms'] = data['total_bedrooms'].fillna(data['total_bedrooms'].mean())

#Labelling the encoded conversion of a categorical column to an int

data['ocean_proximity'] = data['ocean_proximity'].astype('category')
data.dtypes
data['ocean_proximity'] = data['ocean_proximity'].cat.codes

#Linear Regression on median income
dropcol = ["longitude","latitude","housing_median_age","total_rooms","total_bedrooms","population","households","ocean_proximity","median_house_value"]

x = data.drop(dropcol,axis=1)
y = data['median_house_value']

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2)

print(x_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape)
print(y_test.shape)
```

Comment: To help you find your error, we would need all the lines of codes as some are obviously missing, and we would also need to know what you are trying to do.

Comment: Edited already!

Comment: This is still not clear, but let's try it that way: your chart doesn't make any choice, it only plots what data you're giving it. So if you're not seeing what you were expecting, check your data processing.

Comment: Also, your code is really confusing: you have double imports on multiple libraries, you have four lines with `lidata = pd.DataFrame({'Actual':y_test,'Predict':y_dtpred})` but only two probably change something, you still don't show us the instanciation of your `sklearn` models, you have two commands (from `seaborn` and `matplotlib`) drawing a plot before each plot you show us... So this is really hard to help you here!

Comment: Sorry if I couldn't explain it properly, I'm just a beginner :) But basically, the reason why there are four lines with ```lidata = pd.DataFrame({'Actual':y_test,'Predict':y_dtpred})``` or something similar is because there are 2 charts for both the Linear Regression and the Decision Tree Model.  The reason why I use both is because I want to see which chart shows the most accurate data.

Comment: Also, by the way, here is the Excel file used: file:///C:/Users/Minerva%20Panganiban/Downloads/housing.pdf