# How to make the chart to use Decision model tree instead of Linear Regression?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, linear-regression, decision-tree

I've been trying to make the chart use Decision Tree Modelling. The values were different, it's just that the chart uses the same values.

(I previously asked this under another account: [Dataset keeps on using linear regression instead of decision tree model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76896232/dataset-keeps-on-using-linear-regression-instead-of-decision-tree-model))

Here is the full code:

```
from pandas import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from math import *

import numpy as num
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
%matplotlib inline

import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="white", color_codes=True)

data = DataFrame(read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Datasets/housing.csv"))

print(len(data.columns))
row_count = len(data)
print(row_count)

#Looking for missing data
na = pd.concat([data.isnull().sum()],axis=1)
na[na.sum(axis=1)>0]

#Filling the dataset with the mean values
data['total_bedrooms'] = data['total_bedrooms'].fillna(data['total_bedrooms'].mean())

#Labelling the encoded conversion of a categorical column to an int

data['ocean_proximity'] = data['ocean_proximity'].astype('category')
data.dtypes
data['ocean_proximity'] = data['ocean_proximity'].cat.codes

#Splitting the dataset

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#Linear Regression on median income
dropcol = ["longitude","latitude","housing_median_age","total_rooms","total_bedrooms","population","households","ocean_proximity","median_house_value"]

x = data.drop(dropcol,axis=1)
y = data['median_house_value']

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2)

print(x_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape)
print(y_test.shape)

#Standardizing the X dataset (so it could be understood better), Y dataset is for checking later on since they dont have columns
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
std = StandardScaler()
X_train = std.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = std.fit_transform(X_test)

print(X_test)
print(X_train)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
linreg = LinearRegression()
DT = DecisionTreeRegressor()
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from math import sqrt

linreg.fit(x_train,y_train)
y_pred = linreg.predict(x_test)
print(y_pred)

#Regression Chart
lidata = pd.DataFrame({'Actual':y_test,'Predict':y_pred})
sns.jointplot(x='Actual',y='Predict',data=lidata,kind='reg')

#Plotting predicted and test value
lidata = pd.DataFrame({'Actual':y_test,'Predict':y_pred})
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
lidata = lidata.reset_index()
lidata = lidata.drop(['index'],axis=1)
plt.plot(lidata[:50])
plt.legend(['Actual','Predict'])

DT.fit(x_train,y_train)
y_dtpred = DT.predict(x_test)
print(y_dtpred)

lidata = pd.DataFrame({'Actual':y_test,'Predict':y_dtpred})
sns.jointplot(x='Actual',y='Predict',data=lidata,kind='reg')

lidata = pd.DataFrame({'Actual':y_test,'Predict':y_dtpred})
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
lidata = lidata.reset_index()
lidata = lidata.drop(['index'],axis=1)
plt.plot(lidata[:50])
plt.legend(['Actual','Predict'])
```

Here is the result for the Linear Regression:

```
[259015.28102071 477691.37470101 183694.44706634 ... 320526.31718784
 173087.6503445  221971.14827993]
```

[image]

And here is the result for the Decision Tree Model:

```
[414300. 461400. 172100. ... 458500. 218400. 291800.]
```

[image]

I tried changing up the values, but ended up getting the same results. I don't know what is the solution to the code. What can I try next?

Comment: This is a duplicate [of your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76896232/dataset-keeps-on-using-linear-regression-instead-of-decision-tree-model). Please do not duplicate questions, even if you want to ask it using a different account.